# Symfony2 form builder, choices multiple, excepted array also on sample code

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

After hours of searching on this forum and google no answer worked.
I have tried more types of array like array of arrays, and simple key => value array.

Also i have tried code for: expanded true, and multiple true at http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

I am getting error " Expected an array. 500 Internal Server Error - TransformationFailedException "  When i turn on "multiple" I have tried it with array of arrays and key pair array.

What i want is to do and what its doing.

1. I select videos from database
2. make conversion

   ```
   $video = $this->entityManager->getRepository("CMMSHomeBundle:Video")->findAll();

   if (!$video)
   {
       return '0';
   }

   $video_arr = array();

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($video); $i++)
   {
       //$video_arr[$i]["id"] = $video[$i]->getId();
       //$video_arr[$i]["videoid"] = $video[$i]->getVideoid();
       $video_arr[$video[$i]->getId()] = $video[$i]->getVideoid();
   }
   return $video_arr;
   ```
3. print_f if array is correct: Array ( [1] => X-77txuiVXs [5] => uelHwf8o7_U ) OR Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [videoid] => X-77txuiVXs ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 5 [videoid] => uelHwf8o7_U ) )
4. Do the magick

   ```
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product);
   $form->add('name', 'text');
   $form->add('short', 'textarea');
   $form->add("description", "textarea");
   $form->add("price", "text");
   $form->add("images", "text");
   $form->add('videos', 'choice', array(
       'choices' => $videos,
       'expanded' => true,
       'multiple' => true,
           )
   );
   $form->add("files", "text");
   $form->add("size", "text");
   $form->add("weight", "text");
   $form->add("category", "text");
   $form->add("active", "text");
   $form->add('save', 'submit');
   $form->getForm();
   ```

$form is chained, i unchained it to get correct formating by this soverflow editor.

It wont work :-( As soon i turn on multiple

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use the entity form type instead? http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: thankyou, i ramade  it to entity style